# Select count(*) from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this SQL query which is working as it should when I run it into phpMyAdmin.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) , LENGTH( Number ) AS Numbers
FROM  `history_2015-07-22` 
WHERE Number NOT LIKE  '123%'
OR LENGTH( Number ) <50
GROUP BY Numbers
ORDER BY TIME =  '2015-07-22 00:00:01' ASC
```

I want now to make a simple php page where I want to display the query results on the browser but I can't figure out how to echo it exactly. So i've made this:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT( * ) , LENGTH( Number ) AS Numbers
                         FROM  `history_2015-07-22` 
                         WHERE Number NOT LIKE  '123%'
                         OR LENGTH( Number ) <50
                         GROUP BY Numbers
                         ORDER BY TIME =  '2015-07-22 00:00:01' ASC ");
$result->execute();
foreach ($result as $Numbers)
{
    echo '<div class="container">
                '.$Numbers['COUNT(*)'].'
                '.$Numbers['LENGTH(Number)'].'
          </div>';
}
```

What I want to echo is `Count` and `Length`.
I'm sure is something very simple what I miss but can't figure it out.

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't use an equal assignment. Read the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Use alias `COUNT( * ) as cnt` and in php `$Numbers['cnt'] and $Numbers['Numbers']`

Comment: @Fred-ii- we can use `order by col = 'someval'`  this would push the record on the top for the matching value.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty oh? can you show me some documentation, or is this an undocumented feature? I didn't see it in the manual.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty , thank's that way is work. I've thought I can give one alias like `AS Numbers`.. not for every row.

Comment: Yeah many things are not documented however is a demo how it works http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f0568/1

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty that's very interesting. thanks for the info/demo. I'll make a note of that, *cheers*

Comment: You welcome @Fred-ii-, there are many small small tricks which are not documented properly and looks really weird when we see those things.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty same as not using `:` placeholders in the arrays. Also undocumented (PDO). Required in values, but not in array exec.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty why is paid on last row then

Comment: looks like it is undocumented cuz it drops an egg :>

Comment: @DrewPierce when order is done explicitly on a constant value then it will first order data based on that, now rest of the data could be anywhere, you may need a secondary order clause to arrange them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, can you please explain what you're trying to do exactly with the SQL query?

From what I understand, you can try this:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS ct_all, LENGTH( `Number` ) AS Numbers
                         FROM  `history_2015-07-22` 
                         WHERE `Number` NOT LIKE ('123%')
                         AND Numbers < 50
                         GROUP BY Numbers
                         ORDER BY `TIME` ASC");
$result->execute();
$results = $result->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo $row['ct_all'] . ' // ';
    echo $row['Numbers'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT( * ) as cnts, LENGTH( Number ) AS num
                         FROM  `history_2015-07-22` 
                         WHERE Number NOT LIKE  '123%'
                         OR LENGTH( Number ) <50
                         GROUP BY num
                         ORDER BY TIME =  '2015-07-22 00:00:01' ASC ");
$result->execute();
foreach ($result as $Numbers)
{
    echo '<div class="container">
                '.$Numbers['cnts'].'
                '.$Numbers['num'].'
          </div>';
}
```

Comment: Group by should be `num` not `Numbers` and have you actually reviewed this code you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Here Have a Look I've pointed some issues.

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS ct_all, LENGTH( `Number` ) AS Numbers
                         FROM  `history_2015-07-22` 
                         WHERE `Number` NOT LIKE ('123%')
                         AND Numbers < 50
                         GROUP BY Numbers
                         ORDER BY `TIME` ASC");
    $result->execute();
   // the problem is.. 
   // you are trying to fetch $result but here $result is just executing 
   // you cannot retrive anything unless you didn't declare it 
   /*  here $result has nothing in it; is just executed first
    * declare it 
   */
     $result = $result->execute();
    /* Then Fetch it 
    And then You Can Use You Fetch Var with index to retrive data. 
    e.g */
    $allData = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach ($allData as $SingleData)
{
// here you must place indexes of your Query 
// e.g $SingleData['id'] or $SingleData[0]
        echo '<div class="container">
                    '.$SingleData['COUNT(*)'].'
                    '.$SingleData['LENGTH(Number)'].'
              </div>';
    }
```